# Converting simple html to png image via SVG images and converting to base64 encoding

Tags: javascript, image, svg, base64

I am trying to convert some simple html to a `png` image to be printed on a `pdf`. I do so by creating an `svg` with a foreign object that contains my page's html. My issue is that I am not seeing consistent results between a simple fiddle I made and my actual application despite copy/pasting the same exact code in both places.

I have my system application and I have my fiddle both running the same exact function, and inside that function I basically set a `tempImg.src` to that of my `svg` and then I can draw that image into a canvas and finally grab the `canvas.toDataURL()` which in theory would give a consistent `base64` result that can be used.

```
getChartAndDetailsImageData: function (){
    var me = this,
        tempImg = new Image(900,450);

    var imageLoaded = function (event){
        var canvas  = document.createElement('canvas'),
            img = event.currentTarget;

        canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
        canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;

        var ctx     = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        console.log(dataURL);
    };

    var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="900" height="450"><foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><div><b>Ya YEET!</b><ol><li>Hello World :)</li></ol></div></body></foreignObject></svg>';
    var imgSrc = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(svg);
    console.log(imgSrc);

    tempImg.onload = imageLoaded;
    tempImg.src = imgSrc;
}
```

Now, from running this code I get two different results based on where I am running.

1: The fiddle: my end result image is - 
[image]

Which is the desired result, This is what I expect and need to see

But my system application gives me this resulting image - 
[image]

Which is really shrunk down and looks horrible.

Is there some detail I'm missing about svg's and how to acquire a proper consistent `base64` encoding of the `png` image?

Eg.) Plug both those encodings into this website to visually see the difference (https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

Any help and/or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Edit.) It appears as though I may have figured it out. I just wrapped my inner html with a div and slapped a fontsize on it and now I seem to be getting consistent results. I'm not entirely sure this was the most effective way to achieve the desired results so any sort of explanation and/or other possible fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Y'all!

Comment: How about posting the output images rather than the base64 encoded image.

Comment: My fault, I just added the pics. I left the base64 encodings because they might be helpful to see that the exact same function in the separate environments is producing two different encodings.. very perplexing to me

Comment: which two environments are you comparing? Does adding a viewbox to the svg help?

Comment: I am using a fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2pge) and my works system. I just added a viewbox to the svg like so "viewbox="0 0 900 450" just before the xmlns tag and still did not get the desired results.